# How to get checked checkbox row values from material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I have a angular material table with check box row. Material Table Based on check and unchecked i want to manipulate other field from selected checkbox row value.

Comment: have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028819/bind-check-box-value-in-to-mat-table) ?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use the "selection" method. Using your selection model, you can then list your selected rows. in your .ts file:

```
selection = new SelectionModel<Your_data_model>(true, []);
```

then with a click button or a method of your choosing, you can display or iterated through the selected records using:

```
this.selection.selected
```

You can view the selection in your browser console:

```
console.log(this.selection.selected);
```

Hope this helps.